# wiki and twiki major modes

Tags: major-mode, formatting

Is there an emacs mode for editing and typsetting wiki wiki modes?

What I am looking for is something that could help me writing a properly formatted document for wikipedia.

Comment: checkout [mediawiki.el](https://launchpad.net/mediawiki-el)

Comment: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryHypermedia - search down the page for `Wikipedia/Mediawiki`